# Laravel 4 shows MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am getting this error at the time of when i hit the address bar ,

I fetch data from database and send to the view, that view's working great, but when I hit the address bar tab it shows
`Symfony \Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException`
any help will be great for me...

In my controller:

```
public function getpiece()
{  
    $reportno = $_POST['reportno'];
    $data     = DB::table('reportno')->where('reportno','=',$reportno)->get();


    if(empty($data)) {
        return \Redirect::to('dashboard/client/piece')
            ->with('status','error')
            ->with('message','Data Not  Available');
    } else {       
        return \View::make('dashboard.client.piecewisereport')
            ->with('data',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to you call this action, and http method, for example GET,POST,DELETE or other?

Comment: Probably your POST and GET method in your route are not separated.

Comment: using post  Route::post('getpiece','Controllers\Domain\Client\ClientController@getpiece');

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because when you hit `enter` in the address bar, it is trying to use a `GET` instead of a `POST`, but it finds only a `POST` route. (Route::post).

To solve this, either do:

```
Route::any('getpiece','Controllers\Domain\Client\ClientController@getpiece');
```

And then I'd advise to use something like

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
    //
}
```

and

```
if (Request::isMethod('get'))
{
    //
}
```

to wrap your code. More on this can be found in the [Request Information docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information)

And an alternative method is to address the Controller directly from the routes, as can be found here: [Laravel 4.2 Implicit Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Note: these documentation links link to Laravel 4.2.

Comment: the route was lost , maybe there is a problem in session route?

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer. I forgot to add `@getpiece` in the route

Comment: It's strange you would get a `MethodNotAllowedException` exception on `any`. Did you remove the `Route::post`? Or is it not a `MethodNotAllowedException`?

Comment: yes, i  changed route:: post to Route::any , but same error remains,  MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 0):

I notice your controller method is called `getpost` but your accessing the `$_POST` variable.

I can't tell for certain without looking at your routes file but if your route uses `Route::get('routename')` then it is making use of the wrong HTTP method. If this is the case try changing it to `Route::post('routename')`.

Comment: i am  using  only the post  method

Comment: getpiece is a function name you can take piece() only

Comment: OK, in that case it looks like Ciccio's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `php artisan routes` in a terminal from the root of your project, it lets you check what are your registered routes.

*PS: FYI, in case of Laravel 5 it would be `php artisan route:list`*